# Access an iPad's Photos via the Web or a Linux Computer?

Tags: ipad, icloud, photos, photo-stream

*I have earlier used AirDroid but its quality is unexpected, more [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29265/what-may-cause-airdroid-slowing-down-in-my-own-network) so now looking alternative solution.*

I have iPad but I have no other Apple products. Can I somehow get the images from iPad to my Debian computer with the iCloud.com website? If not, how can I get them from iPad to my computers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iCloud.com doesn't have an interface to access your [Photo Stream](http://www.apple.com/icloud/features/photo-stream.html). However there are other ways to access the photos if you don't have access to iTunes for syncing.

### [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/)

The [iOS Dropbox app](http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/dropbox/id327630330?mt=8) has recently been updated with a feature that can automatically upload all the new photos from your Camera Roll to Dropbox when you open the app. I believe you can even [get bonus Dropbox storage for using the feature](http://www.theverge.com/apple/2012/6/14/3088092/dropbox-ios-1-5-automatic-photo-uploads-gallery-view).

Once the photos are in your Dropbox account, you can access them through the web interface on Dropbox.com or the [Linux client](https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx).

### [AirSharing](http://avatron.com/apps/air-sharing)

The AirSharing app ([$9.99 on the App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/air-sharing/id312686749?mt=8)) is essentially a general purpose file transfer client. It supports FTP, SFTP, WebDAV, Google Docs, Dropbox and more. You can use it to transfer photos from your iPad's Camera Roll (or other albums) to your Debian machine via (S)FTP or a WebDAV folder running on your iPad. If you prefer to avoid a cloud solution like Dropbox, this is probably the way to go.

These are just a couple options, there are certainly others out there (the [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/) app would probably work similarly to Dropbox, and there are other apps similar to AirSharing).

Answer (score 2):

### [iPhoto for iOS Journals](http://www.apple.com/apps/iphoto/)

Create a journal on iPhoto for iOS to store your pictures online with iCloud where other computers can get at them. To store the journal on iCloud tap the share button. Then tap 'Publish to iCloud'. When it is done publishing tap the share button again and select the email to a friend option and just email the link to yourself then download the photos from the webpage. For more info you can visit this Apple support page about sharing journals.

http://support.apple.com/kb/PH3156